# Powershell alter spamfilter office365 on all tenants

Tags: powershell, office365

We have a reseller account that has access to all our tenants.

Our VOIP provider has a fax functionality which will send an email message with wav attachment to a designated email address. Office365 sees this as a spam message, and the VOIP provider doesn't seem to be able to change anything so Office365 does not treat it as spam anymore. The only solution that works for sure, is by whitelisting their domain in the Office365 spamfilter.

I have done this for a few domains now, but given how many tenants we have, I wonder if there is a way to automate this.

I started programming in powershell to see how far I'd be able to get, but I wonder if this is even possible.

So far my code is as follows:

```
    if(-not (Get-MsolDomain -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
    {

        $UserCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 
        Connect-MsolService -Credential $UserCredential
    }

    $Tenants = Get-MsolPartnerContract -All
    $Tenants | ForEach {
        Get-MsolDomain -TenantId $_.TenandID | fl
    }
```

Below some sample output (reselleraccount.onmicrosoft.com is fictive, it shows the actual name of my tenant there, but altered for privacy reasons. I basically get the same block of info about 100 times, the amount of tenants we have):

```
ExtensionData      : System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject
Authentication     : Managed
Capabilities       : Email, OfficeCommunicationsOnline
IsDefault          : True
IsInitial          : True
Name               : reselleraccount.onmicrosoft.com
RootDomain         : 
Status             : Verified
VerificationMethod : DnsRecord

ExtensionData      : System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject
Authentication     : Managed
Capabilities       : Email, OfficeCommunicationsOnline
IsDefault          : True
IsInitial          : True
Name               : reselleraccount.onmicrosoft.com
RootDomain         : 
Status             : Verified
VerificationMethod : DnsRecord

ExtensionData      : System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject
Authentication     : Managed
Capabilities       : Email, OfficeCommunicationsOnline
IsDefault          : True
IsInitial          : True
Name               : reselleraccount.onmicrosoft.com
RootDomain         : 
Status             : Verified
VerificationMethod : DnsRecord
```

I was expecting to get at least the domainnames of each tenant, but this seems to get me information from my reseller account only.

Is there a way to connect to all my tenants or is this simply not possible?

Comment: Doesn’t the Office 365 Administration backend allow you to determine the rules for the spam detection?  I know it allows you to determine when an email will be identified as outside of your organization.  Seems odd that it doesn’t support say RegEx and/or a rule that solely is around the existence of the attachment.  I assume the designated email address doesn’t change?

Comment: @Ramhound yes it does, but there are many tenants. Its still an hour or more work to configure the accept list for the spamfilter for each tenant. And if I want to do this in the future, I have to go through all again. If I can do this with powershell, that would be so much better.